# Can a class extend an abstract class and implement an interface at the same time? (java)

Tags: java, uml, extends, implements

If I have for example a class Foo and also an abstract class Bar and an interface Fizz, can the class implement both in its declaration? Or should the interface first be implemented in the abstract class?

I ask because of this UML Chart: (! the unfilled arrow should point to the abstract class to show that its inherited from the abstract class !)

[image]

```
public class Foo extends Bar implements Fizz {
   ...
}
```

Is my class declaration correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Your UML only shows a dependency from `Foo` to `Fizz`. Nothing else.

Comment: Yes. And Thomas is right -- you probably mean a Realisation rather than a Dependency between Foo and Fizz.

Comment: why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can. The only thing you can't do with class declarations is extend multiple classes.

Comment: Well, that's not the _only_ thing you can't do. Come on now, use your imagination! :)

Comment: @mypetlion well if you only look at extending classes and implementing interfaces, it is (I believe)

Comment: You cannot do `implements Fizz extends Bar` ;)

Comment: You also can't extend final classes or `extends Enum` (directly, at least).

Comment: @user7 true forgot about the order :P

Comment: @mypetlion I said thats the only thing you can't do when extending _classes_, so that still holds true.